# obtain point cloud from depth numpy array using open3d - python

Tags: python, numpy, point-clouds, depth, open3d

I have a 2D numpy array(640X480) containing the depth value per each pixel which I obtained through a rendering system. Now I want to **obtain point cloud** of it.  I tried a lot of methods but I have problem with rotation :

methods I tried:

1. **using open3d-python library:** I found an example and followed these steps:

````
color_raw = o3d.io.read_image("../../test_data/RGBD/color/00000.jpg")
depth_raw = o3d.io.read_image("../../test_data/RGBD/depth/00000.png")
rgbd_image = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(
    color_raw, depth_raw)

    a = o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsicParameters
    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(
        rgbd_image,
        o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(
            o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsicParameters.Kinect2DepthCameraDefault))
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

**Problem**: 
a) I do not have an rgbd image. all I have is a 2d numpy array containing depth values for each pixel which can be saved as png image and used for the parameter depth_raw. 

b) I tried to create a point cloud only from depth image using the function `open3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_depth_image(depth, intrinsic, extrinsic=(with default value), depth_scale=1000.0, depth_trunc=1000.0, stride=1, project_valid_depth_only=True)` but I get error when I try to pass the png image. how can I pass my numpy array into the required image format. 

Please help me the above doubts to proceed further. 

thanks in advance
````

Comment: I know that's not a solution, but You should try [Vedo library](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo). It's easier to use if You want to have interactive 3d point cloud and also if You want to have point cloud that is changing in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
depths must be a [n, n] numpy array, then

```
import open3d as o3d

vertices = []
depths = (your_depth_values)

for x in range(depths.shape[0]):
    for y in range(depths.shape[1]):
        vertices.append((float(x), float(y), depths[x][y]))

pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
point_cloud = np.asarray(np.array(vertices))
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(point_cloud)
pcd.estimate_normals()
pcd = pcd.normalize_normals()
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```