# covert rgb png and depth txt to point cloud

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

I have a series of `rgb` files in `png` format, as well as the corresponding depth file in `txt` format, which can be loaded with `np.loadtxt`. How could I merge these two files to point cloud using `open3d`?

I followed the procedure as [obtain point cloud from depth numpy array using open3d - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606927/obtain-point-cloud-from-depth-numpy-array-using-open3d-python), but the result is not readable for human.

The examples is listed here:

- the source png:[image]
- the pcd result:[image]

You can get the source file from this link [![google drive]](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZNumu7iqgC5JtD5_j4UKLowpBV2cPQ1S?usp=sharing) to reproduce my result.
By the way, the depth and rgb are not registerd.

Thanks.

Comment: What exact code did you use? I Just viewed your depth data in open-cv as a gray scale image and I could at least identify certain items of your desk. Your Pcd image looks pretty different, but some features have some similarity to my grayscale image. It seems your camera position for the pcd is way too close for your scene.

Comment: I transfered the array to pcd just following the methods here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606927/obtain-point-cloud-from-depth-numpy-array-using-open3d-python. I think this line `vertices.append((float(x), float(y), depths[x][y]))`  maybe is uncorrect for my depth file.

Comment: Updated. I loaded depth with numpy and then convert it to `o3d.Image` with `np.astype(np.uint8)`. And the depth visualized in opencv is normal. But an empty point cloud produced. Here is my code https://gist.github.com/Whisht/70858c0d78d79eeb20c3f887436f2397 I used to process the depth and rgb.

Comment: I loaded txt file and image from drive. the shape of numpy array and image is not matching. txt file array is (400,640) However RGB image is (480, 640, 3). 400 and 480 is not good :). You suppose to have one value from txt file for each pixel in your rgb image I believe. Can you explain why is it shapes are not matching and how you want to create pcd in this case

Comment: These files are offered by my colleague, collected with orbbec rgbd camera. I followed the answer below and produced the point clouds. The main purpose is to annotate the 3d bounding boxes for 3d object detection and then use it for robotic grasping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to play a bit with the settings and data and used mainly the answer of your SO link.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

color = o3d.io.read_image("a542c.png")
depth = np.loadtxt("a542d.txt")

vertices = []
for x in range(depth.shape[0]):
    for y in range(depth.shape[1]):
        vertices.append((float(x), float(y), depth[x][y]))
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
point_cloud = np.asarray(np.array(vertices))
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(point_cloud)
pcd.estimate_normals()
pcd = pcd.normalize_normals()
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

However, if you keep the code as provided, the whole scene looks very weird and unfamiliar. That is because your depth file contains data between 0 and almost 2.5 m.
I introduced a cut-off at 500 or 1000 mm plus removed all 0s as suggested in the other answer. Additionally I flipped the x-axis (float(-x) instead of float(x)) to resemble your photo.

```
# ...
vertices = []
for x in range(depth.shape[0]):
    for y in range(depth.shape[1]):
        if 0< depth[x][y]<500:
            vertices.append((float(-x), float(y), depth[x][y]))
```

For a good perspective I had to rotate the images manually. Probably open3d provides methods to do it automatically (I quickly tried pcd.transform() from your SO link above, it can help you if needed).
Results

500 mm cut-off:[image: 500mm cut-off] and 1000 mm cut-off: [image: 1000mm cut-off].

Answer (score 1):

I used laspy instead of open3d because wanted to give some colors to your image:

```
import imageio
import numpy as np
# first reading the image for RGB values
image = imageio.imread(".../a542c.png")
loading the depth file
depth = np.loadtxt("/home/shaig93/Documents/internship_FWF/a542d.txt")
# creating fake x, y coordinates with meshgrid
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(400), np.arange(640), indexing='ij')
#  save_las is a function based on laspy that was provided to me by my supervisor
save_las("fn.laz", image[:400, :, 0].flatten(), np.c_[yv.flatten(), xv.flatten(), depth.flatten()], cmap = plt.cm.magma_r)
```

and the result is this. As you can see objects are visible from front.
[image]

However from side they are not easy to distinguish.
[image]

This means to me to think that your depth file is not that good.

Another idea would be also getting rid off 0 values from your depth file so that you can get point cloud without a wall kind of structure in the front. But still does not solve depth issue of course.

ps. I know this is not a proper answer but I hope it was helpful on identifying the problem.